# How to speed up a query that has a WHERE on a varchar column?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have two columns in the **`users`** table:

- **`id`**:  It's `bitint`, `primary`, `unique`, `auto_increment`, `unsigned` and `not null`
- **`cellphone`**: It's `varchar(15)`, has `index` (btree), `unique`, and `not null`

---

**Noted:**

1. The `users` table has about 1.5 milion rows.
2. The `cellphone` is used as the *username*.
3. The btree index that I have on the `cellphone` column is an composite index like `users(cellphone, type)`

---

The strange part is, the time execution for the following queries is much different.

For the `id`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = x
//=> Time execution: 0.001 sec
```

[image]

And for the `cellphone`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE cellphone = x
//=> Time execution: 1.5 sec
```

[image]

Any idea how can I make the `cellphone` one fast as much as the `id` one?

---

Also, here is the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `f_name` varchar(29) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `l_name` varchar(29) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `national_id_real` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Registered by the user',
 `national_id` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'For customers, it''s for beh pardakht psp (generated randomly)',
 `national_code_verification` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `birth_certificate_number` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `cellphone` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `subscription_expire_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Null means a free user ',
 `email` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` enum('marketer','business_owner','customer','daapapp_member','legal') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `belongs_to` enum('daapapp','baadraan','fartak','ibshop','gooya','acap','ezpay','zarindax') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'daapapp',
 `belongs_to_old` enum('daapapp','baadraan') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'daapapp' COMMENT 'This column created because we changed all baadraan''s users to daapapp. Just keeping the old belongingness here for probabilistic needs in future',
 `came_from` enum('organic','baadraan_api','wizard_landing','sms','api','web_site','organizational_import','myirancell','guarantor') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'organic',
 `role_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `province_id` int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Based on the residence province selected inside the user''s profile page',
 `chosen_province_id` int DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Based on the either pins-arount-me-button or select-province-you-want-to-see-pins-for selectOption on the map',
 `sex` enum('male','female') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `city_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
 `area_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `referral_code` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_parent` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 means, his/her referrer would own 20% of his/her cashback share.',
 `referrer_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `referrer_id_legal` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `tracker_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `referrer_gift_given` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `father_name` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `from` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `postal_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `sheba_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `notification_num` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reputation_num` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'This should never get a negative number if the logic is all correct. Also this makes sense only for "business_owners".',
 `transaction_num` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `wallet_credit` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `ewallet_credit` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' COMMENT 'Only for Daapapp ewallet',
 `password` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `level` enum('default','bronze','silver','golden') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default' COMMENT 'For future gamifications based on the club or "belongs_to" column',
 `avatar` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `remember_token` varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `charity_percentage` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `otp_code` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `has_open_process` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'This column created for handling a semaphore in buying Simcard charge to avoid submitting several requests by clicking quickly on the button. It can be used for other requests/apis too in the future',
 `show_referral` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `app_installed` enum('installed','not_installed') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'installed' COMMENT 'At least once - login by PWA is counted',
 `client_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `fcm_token` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `device_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_agent` enum('android','ios','web') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('pending','active','suspend','inactive') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending' COMMENT '"pending" means the user tried to signup (login for the first time) and still has not entered the right OTP. So, the cellphone number is not verified yet',
 `purchase_experience` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `temp` int DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_unique` (`cellphone`,`type`),
 UNIQUE KEY `referral_code` (`referral_code`),
 KEY `role_id` (`role_id`),
 KEY `area_id` (`area_id`),
 KEY `users_ibfk_4` (`sheba_id`),
 KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
 KEY `referrer_id` (`referrer_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `l_name` (`l_name`),
 KEY `users_ibfk_5` (`city_id`),
 KEY `province_id` (`province_id`),
 KEY `created_at` (`created_at`,`type`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `users_ibfk_7` (`chosen_province_id`),
 KEY `referrer_id_legal` (`referrer_id_legal`),
 KEY `came_from` (`id`,`came_from`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `belongs_to` (`belongs_to`),
 KEY `has_open_process` (`has_open_process`),
 KEY `fcm_token` (`fcm_token`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`area_id`) REFERENCES `location_areas` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`referrer_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`sheba_id`) REFERENCES `shebas` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `location_cities` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `location_provinces` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`chosen_province_id`) REFERENCES `location_provinces` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`referrer_id_legal`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2110840 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: *`SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE cellphone = x`* Do you enter the cellphone criteria value as a number?

Comment: can you show *exactly* what the index is?  a CREATE TABLE would be ideal.  (mysql can generate one for you)

Comment: Yes, it's a number @Akina, But since it starts with `0`, I used `varchar` data-type instead of `int`

Comment: INT column can store zero value easily. For to enter this value into AI column - enable NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO server mode temporarily.

Comment: @Akina I used an external link because the `show create table` result was too long and not related to the question. Anyway I edited my question and added the it.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/cT_fM7R3

Comment: It removes the beginning (leading) `0` for numbers https://dbfiddle.uk/S3G5VqpN

Comment: *It removes the beginning 0 for numbers* You enter numeric `02` - this zero is removed before the insertion or comparing, on the query preparing stage. And in this case you MUST enter the criteria value as a string, if not then `WHERE cellphone = 2` and `WHERE cellphone = 02` produces the same output, rather than `WHERE cellphone = '02'`. PS. I recommend you to use not VARCHAR(15) but CHAR(15) datatype..

Comment: Your "id" query is returning 1 record; your "cellphone" query is returning about 1.5M records - so the relative performance between the two is about what I would expect. I'm not sure why you would expect the two fundamentally different queries to be able to be run in the same time?

Comment: @NickW What?? Both id and cellphone are unique and return only one record

Comment: Is cellphone unique? - you have a compound key on it id_unique` (`cellphone`,`type`)). BTW does the query return anything? and what value is x?

Comment: a unique key on (cellphone,type) is not the same as a key on cellphone.

Comment: I probably should have said "searched" rather than "returned". Look at the "rows" column in the two screenshots you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `cellphone` is `VARCHAR`, you *must* use a string, not an integer in the query to use the `INDEX`.  This is the performance problem.

There is a nasty problem lurking under the hood -- are there dashes, parentheses, leading 0, etc, in the string?  If so consider removing them.  Do this in *two* places -- data entry *and* when building the query to look up.  You may even need to add the country code (for consistency).  After all, hardly any Americans would understand "+1".

If you do get rid of all punctuation, `DECIMAL(15,0)` would suffice and fit in 7 bytes (versus an average of perhaps 10 for `VARCHAR(15)`.  That's not a big difference.

What about "extension" on the end of the number?

I assume you are using `NULL` for all the other possible `sex` values these days?

That table has a lot of personal info; I hope your site is adequately secured.

Aren't there still landlines in some places?  Especially businesses?  Might you need to reach many *different* people through an "Operator".

Comment: I just read your first paragraph and resolved my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @MartinAJ - Good.  I was pretty sure that was the problem.  The other paragraphs are less critical, but advice for your app.

Comment: Yeah read them too, insightful, thx again. Also, since you have lots of experience in databases, could you please tell me what's the best solution to get MySQL backup? Noted that I use the free version of MySQL (and not the enterprise one). You know out project is a FinTech platform, so, all transactions are important for us, we shouldn't have even one transaction lost. Currently we have a cron job that gets a  `mysqldump` on a daily basis, but based on some research, I guess there is a approach that gets a full backup first and update it based on each query logs, do you have any clue?

Comment: @MartinAJ = The mysqldump approach is not bad, but you could lose all the transactions since the last dump.  Other things to research: Replication, Galera and/or InnoDB Cluster, LVM.  There are several discussions on dba.stackexchange.com.